# create a custom String with mapping to sql in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In many classes in my project, I have a `String description` and `static mapping = { description sqlType: 'MEDIUMTEXT' }`.

Is there anyway to declare a `StringMediumText description` which automatically links to a column in the database with `sqlType: 'MEDIUMTEXT'`?

So in the future I just need to declare:

```
Person {
    StringMediumText description 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by defining your own Hibernate user type

```
class Person {
   String description

   static mapping = {
       description type: StringMediumTextType
   }
}
```

You find everything regarding your question in the [Reference Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames). Hope this helps